# CipherOutputStream not working

Tags: java, encryption, stream

I have a problem with the following code.

If I use the ObjectOutputStream everything runs fine but when I try to use the CipherOutputStream I get the following error in the server side.

If I send one file I don't receive it fully.
If I send more than one file the last one to be sended is not received fully but the previous are.

What could it be?

I have seen other posts but they didn't help me.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:128)
    at myCloudServer$myCloudServerThread.run(myCloudServer.java:257)
```

Client code. Sending a file.

```
SocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
clientSocket = socketFactory.createSocket(serverAddress[0], Integer.parseInt(serverAddress[1]));

ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

[...]

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
objectOutputStream.writeObject(sendingClientFiles.size());

for (File sendingClientFile : sendingClientFiles) {
    [...]

    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(128);
    SecretKey secretKeyEncrypt = keyGenerator.generateKey();    

    Cipher cipherEncrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES");   
    cipherEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeyEncrypt);
    CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(objectOutputStream, cipherEncrypt);    

    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sendingClientFile));
    int count = 0;
    while ((count = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        //objectOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    bufferedInputStream.close();
    //objectOutputStream.flush();
    cipherOutputStream.flush();
}
```

Server code. Receiving a file.

```
ServerSocketFactory serverSocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
serverSocket = serverSocketFactory.createServerSocket(port);

Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream  objectInputStream  = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

[...]

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int i = 0;
int receivingClientFiles = (int) objectInputStream.readObject();

while(i < receivingClientFiles) {
    [...]

    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(diretorio + "/" + fileName));
    int count = 0;                      
    int received = 0;
    while (received < fileLength) {
        count = objectInputStream.read(buffer, 0,  buffer.length);
        bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        received += count;
    }
    //while ((count = objectInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
    //  bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    //}

    bufferedOutputStream.close();

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Maybe there's nothing more to read and `count` is -1?

Comment: Vasan the file is not totally received by the server but the client sends the full file

Comment: Please don't leave important code out. What is `objectOutputStream` in `CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(objectOutputStream, cipherEncrypt); ` and how is it created? If it is an actual ObjectOutputStream then why are using it when you're not writing Objects?

Comment: Please include the creation of the stream *in the question* as suggested by James. In the current form the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I have added new code to the post.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have added new code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

In `count = objectInputStream.read(buffer, 0,  buffer.length);` you should max out on the file size (because you may otherwise read bytes from the next file). And that particular file size must be the *encrypted length of the stream*, not the original file size (if they differ, that is).

Comment: Is this answer working for you? Just comment below if you've got questions or other considerations...

Comment: What do you mean with "max out on the file size"? And is this `while (received < fileLength) {
count = objectInputStream.read(buffer, 0,  buffer.length);
bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
received += count;
}` the same as this `while ((count = objectInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);}`?

Comment: Sure thing, but you are concatenating files, right? So if the offset + buffer goes over the amount of bytes in a file then you'd be already progressing into the next file. Could you test retrieving the *encrypted* files in the stream before decrypting them? Programming is about composition and decomposition of both code and *problems*. Divide and conquer.